# Get choices from Choice field type on FieldCollection object?

Tags: development, linq

Is it possible to get the available options on a choice field from the FieldCollection object? I am using a LINQ statement and have no issues getting other properties such as internal name, the field type, etc. Can I get the choices for choice fields in a similar way?

```
FieldCollection fc = //logic to get field collection
var fieldData = fc.Select(d => new 
{
    Title = d.Title,
    InternalName = d.InternalName,
    FieldTypeString = d.TypeAsString,
    //FieldChoices = ??
});
```

Answer (score 1):

please load the Choices by using internal name of the field and get the choices

```
           ClientContext context = new ClientContext(source_site_url);
           List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(list_name);
           Field choice = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("jobtitle");     
           FieldChoice fldChoice = context.CastTo<FieldChoice>(choice);
           context.Load(fldChoice, f => f.Choices);
           context.ExecuteQuery();
           foreach (string item in fldChoice.Choices)
           {
               control_name.Items.Add(item.ToString());
               //add choices to dropdown list
           }
```